# Why a pattern-matching failure is not catching by the exception handler?

Tags: haskell, exception, scotty

Why pattern-matching failure is not catching by my exception handler `excToStr` in this case?

I have a handler of an incoming POST request as under the control of the [Scotty Web framework](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty):

```hs
...
import qualified Web.Scotty as W
...

    W.post "/some/endpoint" $ excToStr "Cannot handle it!" $ do
        b <- W.body

        -- throwString "aaa" <--- THIS IS HANDLED FINE!

        Just x::Maybe SomeMyType <- pure (decode b) -- BUT NOT THIS PATTERN-MATCHING FAILURE!
        liftIO $ print $ show x
        W.text "OK"
```

where `excToStr` is mine and it looks like:

```hs
...
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as LT
...

excH :: (String -> String) -> ActionT LT.Text IO () -> ActionT LT.Text IO ()
excH mkErr m = catchAnyDeep m (W.text . cs . mkErr . show)

excToStr :: String -> ActionT LT.Text IO () -> ActionT LT.Text IO ()
excToStr errMsg = excH (\details -> errMsg <> " (" <> details <> ")")
```

`catchAnyDeep` is from [safe-exceptions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-exceptions) library. I tried another functions as well (`catchAny`, `handle`, `catch`, etc) - without success. The crux of the problem is that when incoming body cannot be decoded successfully (and `decode` returns `Nothing` instead of `Just x`), then pattern-match fails, so I expect that my `extToStr` (ie. `excH`) will handle it because `catchAnyDeep` (and `catchAny`) handles *ANY* exception (including pattern-match failures, right?):

`catchAny :: MonadCatch m => m a -> (SomeException -> m a) -> m a`

and

`catchAnyDeep :: (MonadCatch m, MonadIO m, NFData a) => m a -> (SomeException -> m a) -> m a`.

If I throw just an exception with `throwString` then it works as expected (the exception gets caught). But the pattern matching failure leads to an HTTP internal error 500 with a message "Pattern match failure in do expression at....". How to handle pattern-matching exceptions as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two forms of exceptions in a scotty action (of type `ActionT Text IO`). There are native exceptions in `IO`, and another form added by the `ActionT` transformer. These exceptions are handled separately. The interface is given by [the instances of `ActionT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.12/docs/Web-Scotty-Internal-Types.html#t:ActionT):

- `(MonadCatch m, ScottyError e) => MonadCatch (ActionT e m)` (and similarly the `MonadThrow` instance). This shows that when you use `catch` from `MonadCatch` (or `throwString` from `MonadThrow`, and other variants from the *safe-exceptions* library), you are using the error handling mechanism of the transformed monad `m`, which in Scotty is usually `IO` (it defines `ActionM = ActionT Text IO`).
- `(Monad m, ScottyError e) => MonadFail (ActionT e m)`. `MonadFail` is the constraint used for partial pattern-matches in `do` blocks. It does not require a `MonadFail` from the underlying monad `m`, which indicates that, unlike `MonadThrow`/`MonadCatch`, it uses the exception mechanism provided by the `ActionT` transformer itself. To catch this exception you must look for a combinator in Scotty rather than an auxiliary library, such as [`rescue`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.12/docs/Web-Scotty.html#v:rescue).